# Dependency injection with unique_ptr to mock

Tags: c++, unit-testing, dependency-injection, googlemock

I have a class Foo that uses class Bar. Bar is used only in Foo and Foo is managing Bar, therefore I use unique_ptr (not a reference, because I don't need Bar outside of Foo):

```
using namespace std;
struct IBar {
    virtual ~IBar() = default;  
    virtual void DoSth() = 0;
};

struct Bar : public IBar {
    void DoSth() override { cout <<"Bar is doing sth" << endl;};    
};

struct Foo {
  Foo(unique_ptr<IBar> bar) : bar_(std::move(bar)) {}

  void DoIt() {
    bar_->DoSth();
  }
private:
  unique_ptr<IBar> bar_;
};
```

So far so good, this works fine. However, I have a problem when I want to unit test the code:

```
namespace {
struct BarMock : public IBar {
  MOCK_METHOD0(DoSth, void());
};
}

struct FooTest : public Test {
  FooTest() : barMock{ make_unique<BarMock>() }, out(std::move(barMock)) {}

  unique_ptr<BarMock> barMock;
  Foo out;
};

TEST_F(FooTest, shouldDoItWhenDoSth) {
  EXPECT_CALL(*barMock, DoSth());

  out.DoIt();
}
```

The test fails because the mock object was transfered fo Foo, and setting an expectation on such mock fails.

Possible options of DI:

- by shared_ptr: is too much in this case (Bar object is not shared between Foo any anything else)
- by reference to IBar: isn't an option (Bar is not stored outside Foo, so the Bar object created would be destructed leaving Foo with dangling reference)
- by unique_ptr: isn't testable in the presented way
- by passing by value: isn't possible (copying will occure - same issue as with unique_ptr).

The only solution I got is to store raw pointer to BarMock before Foo become solely owner of BarMock, i.e.:

```
struct FooTest : public Test {
  FooTest() : barMock{new BarMock} {
    auto ptr = unique_ptr<BarMock>(barMock);
    out.reset(new Foo(std::move(ptr)));
  }

  BarMock* barMock;
  unique_ptr<Foo> out;
};
```

Isn't there a cleaner solution? Do I have to use static dependency injection (templates)?

Comment: You may be interested in reading [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616475/can-google-mock-a-method-with-a-smart-pointer-return-type/11548191#11548191).

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: thank you for the link. I've already seen it and it works for methods that take unique_ptr as a parameter - but I'm not sure one could apply this approach for constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all, I ended up using this approach everywhere:

```
struct FooTest : public Test {
  FooTest() : barMock{new BarMock} {
    auto ptr = unique_ptr<BarMock>(barMock);
    out.reset(new Foo(std::move(ptr)));
  }

  BarMock* barMock;
  unique_ptr<Foo> out;
};
```

and it works fine with `gtest/gmock`.

Answer (score 4):

Not something I would recommend in production environment actually, but *aliasing constructor* of `shared_ptr` represents maybe a dirty and working solution for your case.
A minimal, working example (that doesn't use *gtest*, sorry, I'm from mobile app and can't test it directly):

```
#include<memory>
#include<iostream>
#include<utility>

struct IBar {
    virtual ~IBar() = default;  
    virtual void DoSth() = 0;
};

struct Bar : public IBar {
    void DoSth() override { std::cout <<"Bar is doing sth" << std::endl;};    
};

struct Foo {
    Foo(std::unique_ptr<IBar> bar) : bar(std::move(bar)) {}

    void DoIt() {
        bar->DoSth();
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<IBar> bar;
};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Bar> bar = std::make_unique<Bar>();
    std::shared_ptr<Bar> shared{std::shared_ptr<Bar>{}, bar.get()};
    Foo foo{std::move(bar)};
    shared->DoSth();
    foo.DoIt();
}
```

I guess your test would become something like this:

```
struct BarMock: public IBar {
    MOCK_METHOD0(DoSth, void());
};

struct FooTest : public testing::Test {
    FooTest() {
        std::unique_ptr<BarMock> bar = std::make_unique<BarMock>();
        barMock = std::shared_ptr<BarMock>{std::shared_ptr<BarMock>{}, bar.get()};
        out = std::make_unique<Foo>{std::move(bar)};
    }

    std::shared_ptr<BarMock> barMock;
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> out;
};

TEST_F(FooTest, shouldDoItWhenDoSth) {
    EXPECT_CALL(*barMock, DoSth());
    out->DoIt();
}
```

---

What does the [*aliasing constructor*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) do?

```
template< class Y > 
shared_ptr( const shared_ptr<Y>& r, element_type *ptr );
```

> The *aliasing constructor*: constructs a `shared_ptr` which shares ownership information with `r`, but holds an unrelated and unmanaged pointer `ptr`. Even if this `shared_ptr` is the last of the group to go out of scope, it will call the destructor for the object originally managed by `r`. However, calling `get()` on this will always return a copy of `ptr`. It is the responsibility of the programmer to make sure that this `ptr` remains valid as long as this `shared_ptr` exists, such as in the typical use cases where `ptr` is a member of the object managed by `r` or is an *alias* (e.g., downcast) of `r.get()`

Comment: +1 for aliasing constructor of shared_ptr, good to know. If I understand it correctly, the shared_ptr created with aliasing constructor is not managing the ptr passed, so it works as a regular raw pointer. Or is there any advantage in using it instead of a raw ptr?

Answer (score 2):

You can keep a reference to the mocked object before passing it to the constructor.  I think it makes the code a tad bit brittle, due to member initialization ordering, but it is clearer semantically what it means.  Ownership of `BarMock` still belongs solely to `Foo`, with a reference handle kept by `FooTest` (similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11277283/3177701)).

Basically the same as your answer, but using reference instead of a raw pointer

```
class FooTest : public ::testing::Test
{
    protected:
        FooTest() :
            bar_mock_ptr(std::make_unique<BarMock>()),
            bar_mock(*bar_mock_ptr),
            foo(std::move(bar_mock_ptr))
        {}
    private:
        // This must be declared before bar_mock due to how member initialization is ordered
        std::unique_ptr<BarMock> bar_mock_ptr; // moved and should not be used anymore
    protected:
        BarMock& bar_mock;
        Foo foo; //ensure foo has the same lifetime as bar_mock
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem in the production code: whenever `Foo` is created, `IBar` reference needs to be passed to it - meaning that whoever manages `Foo`, needs to manage `IBar` while I want to have `IBar` managed by `Foo` so that the user of `Foo` can just inject the dependency, but doesn't have to manage the lifetime of it.

Comment: I'm not changing the definition of `Foo`.  It is still taking and keeping a unique pointer to `IBar` (i.e. managing `IBar`).  I'm just keeping a reference to `IBar` before passing it to `Foo` for testing/mocking sake

Comment: you're right - my bad, I haven't noticed. Nice approach.