# GMock leaking memory

Tags: c++, testing, googletest

**Code**

```
class A {
 public:
  void doit() {...}
}

class B {
 public:
  explicit B(unique_ptr<A> a): a_(move(a)) {}

  void run() {
    a_->doit();
  }

 private:
  unique_ptr<A> a_;
}
```

**Test Code**

```
class MockA : public A {
 public:

  MOCK_METHOD0(doit, void(void));
}

TEST(BTest, Test) {
  auto mockA = std::make_unique<A>();
  EXPECT_CALL(*mockA, doit(_)).Times(1);

  B b(std::move(mockA));
  b.run();
}
```

When running this code it leaks

ERROR: this mock object (used in test BTest.Test) should be deleted but never is. Its address is @0x1234.

Since expectations are supposed to run during destruction I am not sure why its causing issues.

I tried shared_ptr alias method as described here - [Dependency injection with unique_ptr to mock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40508033/dependency-injection-with-unique-ptr-to-mock) but even still I get that exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `class A` needs to have virtual destructor, otherwise destructor for `class MockA` is not executed.

Comment: @jack_carver Same thing: `doIt()` is not virtual