# C++ - Smart Pointers - Access Violation Reading Location 0xDDDDDDDD

Tags: c++, pointers, googletest

I'm currently creating a test for a legacy code and stuck with this error message when running my test (see below):

```
Exception thrown at 0x0F5001EF (Control.dll) in sample.exe:
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xDDDDDDDD.
```

I understand that 0xDDDDDDDD means code was trying to access an already deleted pointer.  But what I do not understand is where it was 'prematurely' deleted.

I've kept it to the very bare minimum. Here is my code

```
CDevice::CDevice() 
{
    numLedRows = numLedCols = 0;
}

CDevice::~CDevice()
{
   std::cout << "destructor!" << std::endl;
}

HRESULT CDevice::Init(IDevice* control)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    deviceCtl.reset(control);
    return hr;
}
```

where:

```
std::unique_ptr<IDevice>   deviceCtl;
```

---

And my test:

```
TEST_F(deviceControlTest, test2)
{
     sut_->Init(deviceMock_.get());
}
```

where

```
std::unique_ptr<CDevice> sut_;
std::unique_ptr<DeviceMock> deviceMock_;
```

and in SetUp...

```
sut_ = std::make_unique<CDevice>();
deviceMock_ = std::make_unique<DeviceMock>();
```

I have also tried using shared_ptr for DeviceMock, same behavior.

Is this something wrong with my code? Or is it my test??
Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question

Comment: `0xDDDDDDDD` is one of way some compiler indicates that pointer was not initialized to specific value.

Comment: Hard to tell what's going on with only snippets of code, but I see that `deviceMock_` is a `unique_ptr<DeviceMock>`, which you then pass to `Init()`, which then `reset()`s `deviceCtl` with it... so now you have *two* smart pointers, *either* of which will `delete` the pointer held when it's going out of scope. That's fishy, a pointer should only ever have *one* owner... is `deviceMock_` still in existence when the exception is thrown?

Comment: You need to make a better effort of  supplying a [mcve], similar to [this](https://www.ideone.com/fTx6nA)

Comment: `.get()` is not a valid way of transferring ownership out of a `unique_ptr`.  As @DevSolar points out you are violating the uniqueness precondition.

Comment: Thanks! I have now updated my code to use shared_ptr instead.  However, I still get the same error.  But if I use ```deviceCtl = control;``` instead of ```deviceCtl.reset(control);``` then the error disappears. What could be the reason for this??

Comment: Have you read any of the comments? We need a _complete_ example to tell exactly what happens. You say you are now using shared_ptr. If you are still using .get(), though, your code is still broken. _We can't tell, because you are only showing snippets instead of a true example._ Voting to close.

Comment: Switch your smart pointer to std::weak_ptr, or much better [boost intrusive_ptr](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have double delete issue here: both `deviceMock_` and `deviceCtl` are handling same pointer. It is deleted twice (doeasn't matter if for unique and shared ptr) once when `CDevice` dtor is called and it's member, including the smart ptr used and once when `deviceControlTest` dtor is called. Please note that in gtest the call order is always the same for *each* test: test suite ctor, test suite setup, test body, test suite teardown, test suite dtor). Options:

1. Use shared_ptr and copy it inside `Init` (do not reset it, just assign `deviceCtl = control;`).
2. Inject via unique_ptr using approach [from this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40508033/dependency-injection-with-unique-ptr-to-mock)