# Passing a mock as a unique_ptr when base class does not have a virtual destructor

Tags: c++, googlemock

I have a library class that I need to mock in one of my tests, and the object that accepts it takes a `unique_ptr` to one. After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64816256/1103734), I assumed I could just do something like this.

```cpp
class LibraryClassMock : public LibraryClass {
 public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(do, void());
};

TEST(ProxyServiceTest, RequestMade) {
    auto mock = std::make_unique<LibraryClassMock>();
    auto mockPtr = mock.get();

    // Setup mock
    EXPECT_CALL(*mockPtr, do()).Times(1);
   
    // Signature of constructor is MySerivce(std::unique_ptr<LibraryClass>)
    MyService service{std::move(mock)};
    proxyService.runCommand("cmd");
}
```

Unfortunately, `LibraryClass` does not have a virtual destructor (nor can I add one), and because `MyService` holds a pointer of the form `unique_ptr<LibraryClass>`, this scope ending causes a leak (as the mock's destructor is not called). Without reworking `Service` to accept a `shared_ptr`, is there a way to work around this? In my application, `service` should be controlling the lifetime of the object passed in, but I need to mock it for my test.

Comment: If you cannot change the `LibraryClass`' destructor, you should have it as a member instead of inheriting it.

Comment: Can you not change LibraryClass?  If it has virtual methods already, I believe making its destructor virtual is the most straightforward way.

Comment: I can not change `LibraryClass`; sorry, I forgot to mention.

 @김선달 Is it possible to create a mock with the mocked class as a member? I've only ever seen it as inheritance in gmock.

Comment: You can't change `LibraryClass`, but can you change `MyService` to take in something with a virtual destructor that has `LibraryClass` as a member?

Comment: I can, but I'd prefer to avoid it if at all possible.

Comment: Personally, I'd change MyService to take a shared_ptr.  Existing users can still provide a unique_ptr, and the shared_ptr will be directly constructed from that.  I'm not sure there is a cleaner solution than that, given your constraints.

Comment: Yeah, this might be the way to go. I was just wondering if there was perhaps some obvious way to work around it :)

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce some stub classes and wrapper that don't need a destructor.  Then you put the g-mock methods on the stub class.

```
class TestLibraryClass {
public:
    virtual void do() {};
}

class LibraryClassMock : public TestLibraryClass {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(do, void());
};

class LibraryClassMockWrapper : public LibraryClass {
public:
    LibraryClassMock* pMock;

    void do() override {
       pMock->do();
    }
};


TEST(ProxyServiceTest, RequestMade) {

    auto mock = new LibraryClassMock();

    // Setup mock
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, do()).Times(1);

    // setup unique_ptr
    std::unique_ptr<LibraryClass> upWrapper(new LibraryClassMockWrapper()); // upWrapper owns mockWrapper lifetime, but not mock
    upWrapper->pMock = mock;
  
    // Signature of constructor is MySerivce(std::unique_ptr<LibraryClass>)
    MyService service{std::move(upWrapper)};
    proxyService.runCommand("cmd");

    delete mock;
}
```

Comment: Isn't that undefined behavior, when the upWrapper is deleted in the service scope, since there is no virtual destructor?

Comment: @DaveS - I'm not a language lawyer, so I don't know if it's truly undefined behavior.
But I wouldn't let something that pedantic cause me grief for writing *test code* to work around a mocking conundrum.

Comment: True, but since the original problem the OP is trying to solve is the same problem (deleting a base class without a virtual destructor), this isn't much of a solution.