# EXPECT_CALL returns "Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active"

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I have the following scenario where I am invoking `EXPECT_CALL` to set the return value of the function `Foo` to `true` however I am getting the following error

```
Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active
```

One essential thing I have seen is passing an object to `EXPECT_CALL` which is the case here. As in `classPtr` is a valid pointer to the `MockClass` object.

// Class Under Test

```
class Feature
{
    [[maybe_unused]] virtual bool Foo(const std::string& digit, int number);
};
```

// Mock class

```
class MockClass : public Feature
{
  public:
  MOCK_METHOD(bool, Foo, (const std::string& digit, int number),
              (override));
};
```

// Test class

```
class UtClass : public Ut
{
   public:
   std::unique_ptr<MockClass> classPtr = std::make_unique<MockClass>());
}

TEST_F(UtClass, Test)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(*classPtr, Foo("A", 5))
    .WillOnce(Return(true));   // Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You do not call `Foo`. "Never called" is an expected error.
2. You should create and destroy `MockClass`, use local `MockClass mock_class` in the test case `TEST_F(UtClass, Test)`, otherwise you will get errors about mock object leaks.

It is supposed to be something like this

```
class Feature {
  [[maybe_unused]] virtual bool Foo(const std::string& digit, int number);
};

class Consumer {
 public:
  bool Eat(Feature *f) {
    return f->Foo("A", 5);
  }
};

class MockClass : public Feature {
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD(bool, Foo, (const std::string& digit, int number), (override));
};

class UtClass : public ::testing::Test {
};

TEST_F(UtClass, Test) {
  MockClass mock;
  EXPECT_CALL(mock, Foo("A", 5)).WillOnce(Return(true));

  Consumer consumer;
  consumer.Eat(&mock);
}
```

Comment: 1. How should `Foo()` be invoked then? 2. Shouldn't unique_ptr take care of deallocation? It's not a raw pointer which needs to be manually deallocated from my understanding

Comment: 1. You can call `Foo()` directly in the test like `classPtr->Foo("A", 5);` but this won't test much. Usually this is done together with dependency injection, i.e. when you pass `classPtr` to some other class that is under test and set expectation that this other class will do with your `classPtr`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40508033/dependency-injection-with-unique-ptr-to-mock. 2. The code you provided is fine, no need to deallocate the unique_ptr. `UtClass` ctor creates the `unique_ptr` (before `TEST_F` is called) and dtor will deallocate it (after `TEST_F` is finished).

Comment: *Shouldn't unique_ptr take care of deallocation?* You should not use the smart pointer at all. `MockClass mock_class;`, the local variable in `TEST_F`. "Mock object leak" is not a memory leak, it's a possible runtime error in Google mock post conditions.

Comment: are you implying to use `EXPECT_CALL(*classPtr, classPtr->Foo("A", 5))`? that won't work @Quarra

Comment: thanks for the snippet. you wouldn't use a `unique_ptr` per se? why not?

Answer (score 0):

What wasn't initially clear to me when starting with Google Mock is that `EXPECT_CALL()` functions as a configuration that needs to be set BEFORE your test code runs.

The typical workflow in Google Test follows these steps:

- Invoke the code under test with predetermined input.
- Assert some output (e.g., with ASSERT_EQ).

However, the Google Mock workflow differs:

- Set up your mocks.
- Configure the expected mock behavior (using `EXPECT_CALL()`).
- Execute the code under test; this code should invoke your mocks.
- While you can still assert some output values at this stage, remember that `EXPECT_CALL()` must be configured BEFORE executing the code under test.

Attempting to execute code and THEN invoking `EXPECT_CALL()` results in the `Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active` warning.

This misunderstanding was critical for me.