# Mocking free function gives never called fail on unit test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I am trying to write unit tests for a socket app. I am using the `<sys/socket.h>` header. In order to test a method, I should mock the socket free functions, so the method is tested in isolation from its dependencies. Here is my attempt, following [this](http://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html#MockingNonVirtualMethods) instructions:

Test file:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include "path/to/ClientConectionHeader"
#include <sys/socket.h>

using ::testing::AtLeast;

class EstablishSocketInterface {
    public:
    virtual int establishSock(int domain, int type, int protocol) = 0;
};

class EstablishSocket : public EstablishSocketInterface {
    public:
    int establishSock(int domain, int type, int protocol) override {
        return socket(domain, type, protocol);
    }
};

class MockSocket : public EstablishSocket {
    public:
    MOCK_METHOD(int, establishSock, (int domain, int type, int protocol));

};

TEST(ClientConnection, ClientConnectionConstructor) {
    MockSocket mockSocket;
    EXPECT_CALL(mockSocket, establishSock(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))
        .Times(AtLeast(1));

    std::string serverIp="127.0.0.1";
    int port=49151;
    ClientConnection client(serverIp,port);
    
}
```

Header of the class I am testing:

```
#pragma once

class ClientConnection
{
public:
    ClientConnection(std::string& serverIp_input,int port_input);
  
private:
    int socketfd;
    const char* serverIp;
    int port;

    bool ExitProgram;   
};
```

Constructor definition:

```
ClientConnection::ClientConnection(std::string& serverIp_input, int port_input) {
    this->socketfd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (this->socketfd < 0) {
        perror("socket");
    }
    this->serverIp = serverIp_input.c_str();
    this->port = port_input;
    this->ExitProgram = false;
}
```

The test fails with the following:
Failure

```
Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL(mockSocket, establishSock(2, SOCK_STREAM, 0))...
         Expected: to be called at least once
           Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active
[  FAILED  ] ClienConection.ClientConectionConstructor (0 ms)
```

The constructor calls the socket() function itself, does not use the mocked one. Dependency injection can work but requires changing the original code. I don't think this is the right approach. Also, to use `EXPECT_EQ()` to check whether the fields are valued the same as the arguments I pass to the constructor, I need getters, which also requires to be added, but are not needed in the 'production' code.

So how do I gtest my methods as I mock the `socket()`, `send()`, `recv()`, `close()` functions from the `<sys/socket.h>` header?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `establishSock` is not a free function, it's a class member function. You only create `mockSocket` and don't use it. How do you expect it can call the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EstablishSocketInterface` is never used in the scope of `ClientConnection` so `establishSock` is never called (no matter if we consider `EstablishSocket` or `MockSocket`. You need to use some form of the technique called 'dependency injection' (e.g. see [Dependency injection with unique_ptr to mock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40508033/dependency-injection-with-unique-ptr-to-mock)). You'll need to wrap all methods (like `socket(), send(), recv(), close()`) in an interface and use this interface everywhere where you would normally used `sys/socket.h` directly.

There's also another technique - the one mentioned in the original question. It requires that all your code is templated so it's not that easy to use. If you insist on it though, then `ClientConnection` would need to be a templated class with `socket` as template parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I did it with dependency injection and wrapped all methods in an interface. In the test, I am creating an object from the original class and pass the mocked interface to it. Is it necessary to have a parent class and both the 'production' and test classes to inherit, in order to use each one for its purpose

Comment: Using the base class (the best would be a pure virtual class w/o any fields, just pure virtual methods as you did, just remember to add virtual dtor) is the way to go: keeps the code clean and forces the code to be oriented against abstractions, not implementations. It makes it more testable. I was using different approaches over the years, and common base class works best in 99% of situations (for me)

Comment: Guess you mean the interface. I was talking about the main class "ClientConnection" that we inject it with the socketInterface. Do I have to mock the "ClientConnection" class itself ? or only if the "ClientConnection" is being injected into some other class. Thanks in advance, I will mark the question solved after your response.

Comment: You're right - there's no need to mock `ClientConnection` yet. Once you start using it in other classes, it will need to be mocked for unit testing. Users of `ClientConnectionInterface` don't need to rely on `EstablishSocketInterface` anymore - users of `ClientConnection` will not be aware of what is used internally for the socket communication. This is the power of good interfaces and dependency injection - dependencies are clear and low-level details do not influence high-level abstractions. You'll need some kind of integration tests with non-mocked objects, but this is a different topic.